# Accordion set active from localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

I've got a jQuery UI accordion that I need to remember its state (which header was last opened).

Here is my swing at it:

```
var storedActive = localStorage.getItem("storedActive");
if (isNaN(storedActive)){
    storedActive = false;
}
console.log(storedActive);
jQuery('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    header: 'h4',
    active: storedActive,
    activate: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.newHeader.context){
            storedActive = ui.newHeader.context.id.slice(-1); //getting id of clicked header
        }else{
            storedActive = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem("storedActive", storedActive);
    }
});
```

This `console.log(storedActive)` in the line 5 proves that the value of the last clicked header is remembered and restotred correctly. The problem is that accordion doesn't open any header.

What's strange is when I put the value `storedActive` manually, accordion opens the header as it should. It just has some problem when the value is restored from localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to use parseInt when getting variable from localStorage. Now everything works correctly. Thx  Ninsly!

```
var storedActive = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("storedActive"));
if (isNaN(storedActive)){
    storedActive = false;
}
console.log(storedActive);
jQuery('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    header: 'h4',
    active: storedActive,
    activate: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.newHeader.context){
            storedActive = ui.newHeader.context.id.slice(-1); //getting id of clicked header
        }else{
            storedActive = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem("storedActive", storedActive);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {        
        localStorage.setItem("AccordionId", $(this).accordion("option", "active"))
    },
    active: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("AccordionId"))
}
```

Replace "AccordionId" by an unique id for this accordion if you get multiple accordion in your page.

It works also for Jquery Tabs